# Icons in Jtable Cell

Tags: netbeans, jtable, icons

Im trying to fill my Jtable with an Icon through Object array:

```
 Object []datos = new Object [10];


TableCellRenderer renderer = new JComponentTableCellRenderer();

 TableColumnModel columnModel = tbRegistradas.getColumnModel();



    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){



            if(rs.getString(7)!= null)
            {
               // datos[0]="SIHAY";

              JLabel lblVerde = new JLabel();
              lblVerde.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images\\led-green.gif")); 

              datos[0] = lblVerde.getIcon();




            }
            else
            {
               // datos[0]="NOHAY";

            }

            datos[1]=rs.getString(1);
            datos[2]=rs.getString(2);
            datos[3]=rs.getString(3);
            datos[4]=rs.getString(4);
            datos[5]=rs.getString(5);
            datos[6]=rs.getString(6);
            datos[7]=rs.getString(7);
            datos[8]=rs.getString(8);
            datos[9]=rs.getString(9);



            modelo.addRow(datos);
        }

        tbRegistradas.setModel(modelo);
```

The problem is first row gets the icon path instead the image:

https://www.dropbox.com/home/TI%20CEAIP/JAIME?preview=11715430_10155770396255137_569453658_o.jpg